# How to get Database ID from a Custom ListView()

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I want to get the database row ID when i am gonna click a list item. In my Custom list view adaper , i  used onClickListener, from where i wanna get the ID. please anyone help me....

**this is my custom list view adapter**

```
public class Quiz_list_adapter extends BaseAdapter{


Context context;
ArrayList<String> aL1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> aL2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> aL3 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> aL4 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> aL5 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> aL6 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> aL7 = new ArrayList<>();

QuizDatabaseHelper myDb;



private static LayoutInflater  inflater = null;

public Quiz_list_adapter(QuizReminder mainAct, ArrayList<String> a1,ArrayList<String> a2,ArrayList<String> a3,
                         ArrayList<String> a4,ArrayList<String> a5,ArrayList<String> a6,ArrayList<String> a7){
    aL1 = a1;
    aL2 = a2;
    aL3 = a3;
    aL4 = a4;
    aL5 = a5;
    aL6 = a6;
    aL7 = a7;

    context = mainAct;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    myDb = new QuizDatabaseHelper(context);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return aL1.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class MyHolder{
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, tv6, tv7;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final MyHolder myHolder = new MyHolder();
    final View myView;

    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_quiz_layout, null);

    myHolder.tv1 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    myHolder.tv2 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.details);
    myHolder.tv3 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.hour);
    myHolder.tv4 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.minute);
    myHolder.tv5 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.day);
    myHolder.tv6 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.month);
    myHolder.tv7 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.year);

    myHolder.tv1.setText(aL1.get(position));
    myHolder.tv2.setText(aL2.get(position));
    myHolder.tv3.setText(aL3.get(position));
    myHolder.tv4.setText(aL4.get(position));
    myHolder.tv5.setText(aL7.get(position));
    myHolder.tv6.setText(aL3.get(position));
    myHolder.tv7.setText(aL5.get(position));





    myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Integer deletedRow = myDb.deleteData(String.valueOf(position));

            aL1.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            if(deletedRow >0){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data Deleted !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"Data not Deleted !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });


    return myView;
}
}
```

**this is my database helper class**

```
public class QuizDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quiz.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "quiz_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "TITLE";
public static final String COL_3 = "DETAILS";
public static final String COL_4 = "HOUR";
public static final String COL_5 = "MINUTE";
public static final String COL_6 = "YEAR";
public static final String COL_7 = "MONTH";
public static final String COL_8 = "DAY";

public QuizDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "TITLE TEXT, DETAILS TEXT, HOUR TEXT, MINUTE TEXT, YEAR TEXT, MONTH TEXT, DAY TEXT)" );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String title, String details, String hour, String minute,
                          String year, String month, String day){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COL_2, title);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, details);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, hour);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, minute);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, year);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, month);
    contentValues.put(COL_8, day);


    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if(result == -1){
        return  false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}


public Cursor getAllData(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME, null);

    return result;
}


public boolean updateData(String id,  String title, String details, String hour,
                          String minute, String year, String month, String day){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, title);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, details);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, hour);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, minute);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, year);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, month);
    contentValues.put(COL_8, day);

    db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[] { id });

    return true;

}

public Integer deleteData(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"ID = ?",new String[] {id});

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your QuizDataBaseHelper add this method

```
public Integer getId(int position){
    int id = 0;
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME, null);
        cur.moveToPosition(position);
        id = cur.getInteger(1);
        cur.close();
   return id;
}
```

call it on your item click; I have not executed it, but this is the way to get your data, if there are any problems, do mention them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

use `setOnItemClickListener` not onClickListener outside of the adpater i.e. in the relevant activity. **id** (assuming a cursor adapter) is then provided.

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    int position,
                                    long id) {
                ......
            }
        });
```

Similar for LongClick's.